# How can I run a nested for loop in R to import data tables from DOMO?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, nested, iteration

I have two lists that represent data tables in Domo which I am using the Domo API to retrieve. The ID's are id's of the data tables within domo. I would use the DomoR::fetch() function to fetch the table using these id's. I want to name each table a, b, and c respectively.

```
id = list(1,2,3)
tablename = list(a,b,c)
```

How could I achieve the below by using for loops?

```
a<-DomoR::fetch(1)
b<-DomoR::fetch(2)
c<-DomoR::fetch(3)
```

The result should be three dataframes named a,b,c

Comment: Can you try `lst1 <- lapply(1:3, function(i) DomoR::fetch(i))` or with `for` loop `lst1 <- vector("list", 3); for(i in 1:3) lst1[[i]] <- DomoR::fetch(i)`

Comment: I apologize, the 1:3 id's are not meant to be taken literal. They are actually not in any sort of order. How would i do this if the id's were a3478de, sefh334, and wrfiu24 for example?

Comment: lets say yo have ids' in a `vector` v1, then `for(i in seq_along(v1)) lst[[i]] <- DomoR::fetch(v1[i])`

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Does it work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `for` loop, we can loop over the sequence of the `vector`, assign the output to the `NULL` `list` created

```
lst1 <- vector("list", length(v1))
names(lst1) <- v1
for(i in seq_along(v1)) lst[[i]] <- DomoR::fetch(v1[i])
```

To extract

```
lst1[["a3478de"]]
lst1[[v1[1]]]
```

where

```
v1 <- c("a3478de", "sefh334", "wrfiu24")
```

Comment: Thank so much, this works. Now I have a list of dataframes that I would like to extract and name based on a vector of table names. How I could i do this?

Comment: @MichaelLopez  Just name the `lst1` with `v1` and then you can extract with `lst1[[v1[1]]]`.  Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Consider `lapply` to iteratively retrieve your data frames and `setNames` to name the list elements.

```
v1 <- c("a3478de", "sefh334", "wrfiu24")

lst1 <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(v1), DomoR::fetch), v1)
```

It is usually advised to work with **one** list of many similar data frames than many separate, similar data frames flooding your global environment. You lose no functionality of data frame if stored in a list, simply the reference changes:

```
lst1$`a3478de`
lst1$`sefh334`
lst1$`wrfiu24`
```